# Удалить ключ из словаря по его значению

Tags: python, dict, key, delete, key-value

Есть словарь вида:

```py
dict_ = {
    "key1": value1,
    "key2": value2,
    "key3": value3,
    "key4": value4
    }
```

Мне нужно удалить ключ `key1` если `value1` равно 1 и ключ `key3` если `value3` равно 3. Т.е. по сути мне надо удалять ключи не по их названию, а по их значению.
Это можно как-то реализовать?

Comment: Это можно сделать циклом, пройдитесь по всем `dict.itmes()` и сравнивайте значения. По нахождению нужного значения берете ключ у удаляйте по ключу `dict.pop(key[, default])`

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант если вы знаете, что значения в словаре уникальны можно использовать
dict comprehension:

```
   test_dict = {"петя" : 22, "саша" : 20, "катя" : 1, "настя" : 21,"антон":22}

   new_dict = {key:val for key,val in test_dict.items() if val != 22}
   
   print('new_dict: ',new_dict)
   new_dict:  {'саша': 20, 'катя': 1, 'настя': 21}
```

Answer (score 2):

Раз вас устраивает логика в вашем ответе, покажу как избавиться от перечисления вручную ключей и сократить условие, и не использовать такой непонятный и нестабильный `or`

```py
key_list = dict_.copy().keys()

for key in key_list:
    if dict_[key] in (1, 3):
        dict_.pop(key)
```

Чтобы не получать исключения при удалении элементов из оригинального словаря, я создаю его копию и забираю только ключи, которые будут храниться в `key_list`. И в условии я вам дал альтернативу конструкции с `or`

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так

```
if dict_["key1"] == 1:
    del dict_["key1"] 

if dict_['key3'] ==3:
    del dict_["key3"]
```

Comment: Таких ключей около 10 и поэтому столько if делать не хочется. Решил по другому. Сделал список с названиями ключей и по циклу прогнал.

Comment: А, ну так тоже можно. Думал у вас их 4,а это маловато  и решил if сделать

Answer (score 1):

Решил вот таким образом:

```py
key_list = ["key1", "key2", "key3", "key4"]

for key in key_list:
    if dict_[key] == 1 or dict_[key] == 3:
        dict_.pop(key)
```

Comment: Предлагаю в таком случае пометить данный ответ как верный, нажав на галочку слева от текста

Answer (score 1):

```py
obj = {
    "key1": 'value1',
    "key2": 'value2',
    "key3": 'value3',
    "key4": 'value4',
    "key5": 'value1'
}

items_for_remove = ['value1', 'value3']

print(
    dict(
        filter(
            lambda x: x[1] not in items_for_remove, 
            obj.items()
        )
    )
)
# {'key2': 'value2', 'key4': 'value4'}
```

Если это делать с привязкой к ключам то можно так:

```py
obj = {
    "key1": 'value1',
    "key2": 'value2',
    "key3": 'value3',
    "key4": 'value4',
    "key5": 'value1'
}

items_for_remove = [('key1', 'value1'), ('key3', 'value3')]

print(
    dict(
        filter(
            lambda x: x not in items_for_remove,
            obj.items()
        )
    )
)
# {'key2': 'value2', 'key4': 'value4', 'key5': 'value1'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно и так попробовать

```
dict_ = {
    "key1": value1,
    "key2": value2,
    "key3": value3,
    "key4": value4
}

for k, v in dict_:
    array_v = []
    array_v.append(v)
    if array_v[1] == 1:
        del dict_['key1']
    if array_v[3] == 3:
        del dict_['key3']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, val in (("key1", 1), ("key3", 3)):
    if dict_[key] == val:
        del dict_[key]
```

Это решение точно для вашего **вопроса**.

---

Но когда я буду следовать логике из вашего **ответа**, то вы хотите что-то другое:

> Удалить **все** ключи из данного списка ключей, которые имеют как
> значение **лубое** из запрещенных чисел.

Тогда мой код будет немножко другим:

```
only_keys = ("key1", "key3")
bad_values = (1, 3)

for key in only_keys:
    if dict_[key] in bad_values:
        del dict_[key]
```

---

*Примечание:*

Когда ключей много и вам *не хочется писать много кавычек и запятых*, как например

```
only_keys = ("key1", "key3", "key7", "key10", "key15", "key23", "key42", "key55")
```

используйте конструкцию

```
only_keys = "key1  key3  key7  key10  key15  key23  key42  key55".split()
```